# Why does a parent div resize to it's child elements?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div boxes which were perfectly aligned and centered, and then when I added text inside the divs, the parent div would stretch and resize to what was inside. I tried using resize: none on the child and parent elements, but that didn't do anything. Also tried using position:absolute; and relative.

HTML

```
<div class="boxes-parent">
    <div class="left-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">About</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">I used to be better at CSS and HTML. Sorry!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Info</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">Info info info.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Contact</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">Phone: (888) 888-8888</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxes-parent {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.left-box, .center-box, .right-box {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 25%;
}

.blue-boxes {
    background-color: #3498db;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    resize: none;
}

.blue-box-header-text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
}

.blue-box-text {
    resize: none;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/0wvyaqbo/

Also, my questions sometimes get downvoted. Have any advice on how I can better format this question? Trying to make it applicable for others. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: what is desired? a parent which can not strech and resize and remain fix sized?

Comment: Also don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things going on:

First, you have your `.right, .center, .left` divs set to `inline-block`. By default, they will always be the width of the content, because of `inline-block`. You need to set them to `block`. Also, `.blue-boxes` should be set to `relative` positioning, not `absolute`.

Here's updated CSS:

```
.boxes-parent {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.left-box, .center-box, .right-box {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}

.blue-boxes {
    background-color: #3498db;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

.blue-box-header-text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
}

.blue-box-text {
    resize: none;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
```

And the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0wvyaqbo/1/

Comment: One more thing... What's strange is that on the jsfiddle, it's perfectly centered. But on the project I'm working on, it's floating left. I was using the google chrome dev tools, and the .boxes-parent margin: 0 auto doesn't seem to be working because there's no defined width and it's "invisible." I set a width of 100% and it did nothing, but when I did width 1% (it was really small) but it was much closer to the middle, do you have any idea what's going on? Searching everywhere...

Comment: meh, sort of figured it out. I used "left: 5.5%" on the parent div, which makes it look center and when I scale down the screen, any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Parent elements likes *divs* are flexible by default and will resize to contain whatever you put in them (height) or whatever their parent element(s)/the browser is doing (width) unless you specify their dimensions.  Use CSS `width` and `height` or `max-width` and `max-height` on the parent to limit its growth.

Generally, a flexible parent is preferred (see: *responsive design*), as some users may choose to modify the font your site is using, increase the font size to improve visibility, or view the site from a different device, and these actions can change the relative size of your content.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Comment: How is a div flexible in width by default? `display: block;width: auto;` is their default style...

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use flexbox.  Simply add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to `.boxes-parent` and change `min-width` to simply `width` for `.left-box`, `.center-box`, and `.right-box`.  Resulting code looks like this:

```css
.boxes-parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.left-box,
.center-box,
.right-box {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px 2% 0;
}
.blue-boxes {
  background-color: #3498db;
  height: 250px;
}
.blue-box-header-text {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes-parent">
  <div class="left-box">
    <div class="blue-boxes">
      <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">About</h1>
      <p class="blue-box-text">I used to be better at CSS and HTML. Sorry!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-box">
    <div class="blue-boxes">
      <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Info</h1>
      <p class="blue-box-text">Info info info.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-box">
    <div class="blue-boxes">
      <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Contact</h1>
      <p class="blue-box-text">Phone: (888) 888-8888</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use `flex: 1 1 25%` for `.left-box`, `.center-box`, and `.right-box`.  This forces them to grow and shrink with each other.

```css
.boxes-parent {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-box, .center-box, .right-box {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
 padding: 10px 2% 0;
}

.blue-boxes {
 background-color: #3498db;
 height: 250px;
}

.blue-box-header-text {
 padding-top: 20px;
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes-parent">
    <div class="left-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">About</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">I used to be better at CSS and HTML. Sorry!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Info</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">Info info info.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Contact</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">Phone: (888) 888-8888</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more info on flexbox, css-tricks has a good [reference sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  Here's the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm going to be using this instead. I gave the other guy "right answer" because he directly stated why it was wrong, but I like your way of doing it much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You used `min-width`, and expected adding content wouldn't cause them to grow?  Just use `width`.
2. Setting `.blue-boxes { position: absolute; }` caused those to shrink to the size of the content.  You could add `width: 100%;`.
3. Since using absolute positioning can mess up layout, a solution that avoids it would be nice.  When you remove the absolute positioning, the blue boxes are no longer aligned vertically.  Set `vertical-align: top;` to fix that.

```css
.boxes-parent {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.left-box, .center-box, .right-box {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.blue-boxes {
    background-color: #3498db;
    height: 250px;
}

.blue-box-header-text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
}

.blue-box-text {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes-parent">
    <div class="left-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">About</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">I used to be better at CSS and HTML. Sorry!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Info</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">Info info info.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
        <div class="blue-boxes">
            <h1 class="blue-box-header-text">Contact</h1>
            <p class="blue-box-text">Phone: (888) 888-8888</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```